# SQL query doesn't work?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to create a table in the database and below is the query that I wrote; does anyone have any idea why it doesn't work?

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'sname varchar(255), city varchar(255), avg int(20), clg# int(20) )' at line 4`

```
CREATE TABLE stud
(
s# int,
sname varchar(255),
city varchar(255),
avg int(20),
clg# int(20)
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use the '#' character in column names.

Comment: It is the answer: you can't use the '#' character in column names.

Answer (score 3):

The `#` is not a valid character for an identifier.  Just remove it:

```
CREATE TABLE stud (
    s int,
    sname varchar(255),
    city varchar(255),
    avg int(20),
    clg int(20)
);
```

You can review the rules for identifiers [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifiers.html).  Note you could also put the name in backticks:

```
    `s#` int,
```

However, I strongly discourage you from using names that need to be escaped.

Answer (score 1):

you cant have # in your table names, change your script to this one and try again.

```
CREATE TABLE stud ( s int, 
sname varchar(255), 
city varchar(255), 
avg int(20),
clg int(20) );
```

Comment: Those are actually column names, but no matter-- this is the answer.  ( You can't use the '#' character in table names either :)

Answer (score 0):

It's not recommended to use '#' to name your identifiers. This is ambiguous for you and other developers on your team. Use this instead

```
CREATE TABLE stud (
sNo int,
sname varchar(255),
city varchar(255),
avg int(20),
clgNo int(20)
);
```

By naming your identifiers descriptively it easier for everyone to understand. However mysql **qouted** identifier naming rules allow  ASCII: U+0001 .. U+007F
see [here](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?number=128).

MySQL Schema object naming [Rules](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifiers.html)